# c# How to create buttons and delete them later by an ID

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I'm struggling to create this script where it generates friend requests. I need to specifically add an id to each button and label so I can remove it when the user clicks either the accept or reject button.

```
Button reqAccept;
Button reqReject;
Label reqUserName;

private void loadFriendRequests()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select UserFirstName, UserLastName, FriendEmail From PendingRequests Where FriendEmail = @fe", connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fe", Properties.Settings.Default.Email);
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                i = 0;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    i++;
                    foreach (object request in i.ToString())
                    {
                        Label userName = new Label();
                        Button accept = new Button();
                        Button reject = new Button();

                        accept.Click += Accept_Click;
                        reject.Click += Reject_Click;

                        userName.Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(dr["UserFirstName"].ToString() + " " + dr["UserLastName"].ToString());

                        accept.Text = "Accept";
                        reject.Text = "Reject";

                        friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(userName);
                        friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(accept);
                        friendRequestPanel.Controls.Add(reject);

                        reqAccept = accept;
                        reqReject = reject;
                        reqUserName = userName;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Requests.Start();
}
private void Reject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(reqUserName);
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(reqAccept);
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(reqReject);

    updateFriendRequestDatabase(2);
}
private void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(reqUserName);
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(reqAccept);
    friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(reqReject);

    updateFriendRequestDatabase(1);
}
```

What the code is doing:
The code above is selecting requests that are the same as the user's email and for every friend request there is, it will add it to 'FlowLayourPanel' by using a label and 2 buttons to either accept or reject.

This is what the GUI looks like: [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F1BD.png)

When the user clicks a button it will obviously go to the event handler but how do I identify which button was pressed?

It needs to be something like:

```
friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(reqUserName##ID##);
```

Comment: You can get that button in the event handler as:
'Button buttonClicked = sender as Button;'

Comment: Use the Tag property of the buttons. You can set it with some identifying value (for example an ID retrieved by your sql query) Then in the button click event just read back that property after casting the sender parameter to a button

Comment: I will also suggest one more thing.
You should extend the button class. and use another field say "id". Then, when you will place the button on the form, assign the relevant value to that field. after that, when you get back the button in click event, you can get that value. Does it make sense, let me know, i will post the whole solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to do is to retrieve from your query the value that uniquely identifies your data. Suppose that your PendingRequest table has an IDRequest then your query could be changed to

```
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select IDRequest, UserFirstName, 
                      UserLastName, FriendEmail 
                      From PendingRequests 
                      Where FriendEmail = @fe", connection))
```

Now when you create your controls dynamically you add also that ID  to the Tag property of every control created by that record

```
foreach (object request in i.ToString())
{
    Label userName = new Label();
    Button accept = new Button();
    Button reject = new Button();

    int idRequest = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IDRequest"]);
    userName.Tag = idRequest;
    accept.Tag = idRequest;
    reject.Tag = idRequest;
    ....
```

Finally in your click event you could retrieve the exact instance of the buttons and label using a code like this

```
private void Reject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button c = sender as Button;
    int idRequest = Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag);
    var ctrls = friendRequestPanel.Controls
                                  .Cast<Control>()
                                  .Where(x => x.Tag != null &&
                                         Convert.ToInt32(x.Tag) == idRequest)
                                  .ToList();
    foreach(Control ct in ctrls)
    {
          friendRequestPanel.Controls.Remove(ct);
          ct.Dispose();
    }
    updateFriendRequestDatabase(2);
}
```

Notice that if you remove the control from the Controls collection you should not forget to Dispose it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get this error: http://oi68.tinypic.com/dbjy2s.jpg

Comment: Fixed it, .Cast<Conrol> should be a method

Comment: Works great but it doesn't remove the 'accept' button.. it removes the 'reject' button and the users name...?

Comment: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @Steve Is it OK if I offer another edit to the code? regarding to the OP's new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953971/c-sharp-i-dont-understand-why-this-button-wont-delete). I added a `ToList()` at the end of query, He should not change the collection in the loop, otherwise some controls will not be removed. For future readers it would be really hard to find the problem in such case.

Answer (score 1):

@Steve has answered it all well. He has already shown you how to fix your current code.

I want to suggest you a better way to structure your current code, so that it looks cleaner and you have more control over the friend request functionality. If you are interested, read further. If you are on tight deadlines then ignore :).

If I was in your place, I would create a user control to represent individual friend request and use events to notify main form in case of accept/reject so that it can remove the request from panel/list. This way main form code (designer + code behind) will become cleaner to read and understand.

**FriendRequestControl**

This would be standard `UserControl` which has contains 1 `Label` (for displaying friend's name and 2 `Buttons` accept and reject.

```
public partial class FriendRequestControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler Accepted;
    public event EventHandler Rejected;

    public FriendRequestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public string FriendName { set { lblFriend.Text = value; } } // TODO add empty/null checks on value

    private void Accept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateRequest(1);
        OnAccepted();
    }

    private void Reject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateRequest(2);
        OnRejected();
    }

    private bool UpdateRequest(int flag)
    {
        // Update db using RequestId and flag
        // TODO Return True/False based if update succeeds
        return true; 
    }

    private void OnAccepted()
    {
        var acceptedHandler = Accepted;
        if (acceptedHandler != null)
        {
            acceptedHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void OnRejected()
    {
        var rejectedHandler = Rejected;
        if (rejectedHandler != null)
        {
            rejectedHandler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Form**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Showing just 1 request here
    var friendRequest = new FriendRequestControl
    {
        RequestId = 100, // As Steve mentioned, you db must return this.
        FriendName = "Friend 1"
    };

    friendRequest.Accepted += FriendRequest_Accepted;
    friendRequest.Rejected += FriendRequest_Rejected;

    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(friendRequest);
}

private void FriendRequest_Rejected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var friendRequest = sender as FriendRequestControl;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(friendRequest);
}

private void FriendRequest_Accepted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var friendRequest = sender as FriendRequestControl;
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(friendRequest);
}
```